# UWP Bases styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I've done some WPF application and I'm doing my first UWP app to test.

I want to know if there is any way to have some base styles, a starting point(little bit like [bootstrap for CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/) in fact), with some predefined styles that could be reused(by example, having a style for "headers", that once applied on a `TextBlock`, would use the `SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush` as `Foreground`, use only format text to uppercase, be bold and a specific police?

I know how to do this myself(even if I'm not that productive with it for now), but it would help to have a starting point which already follow Microsoft guidelines(which color to use, icons, ...).

Is there a solution for that? Include in UWP apps, or with an additional Nuget package, ...?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are not many built-in styles in UWP apps, mostly text styles. You can check these styles out on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources#the-xaml-type-ramp).

Comment: Even with some external libs ?? That would be so usefull

Comment: No, not even a single. The best way to follow the guidelines is to use built-in styles and controls. There are a few articles on the MSDN about colors and icons for UWP apps, you may want to check these out.

Comment: @artista_14 That is for WPF and it absolutely doesn't follow the MS's guidelines.

Comment: @Edlar Dordzhiev This is also available for UWP. You can get source code from here. https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit. Yes it doesn't follow MS guidelines. It is inspired from material design...

Answer (score 0):

you need not any additional Nuget Package to do that....Just create your own custom style in `<Page.Resources></Page.Resources>` and reuse it. It is quite similar to CSS.

[image]

You can check here Microsoft Guidelines for UWP design -
[Design & UI Guidelines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/design)
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Well, I know doing styles, but I was having the impression this is something that should be done for every project, no?

Comment: There are not much resources for designing but I frequently use this toolkit completely inspired from material design...http://materialdesigninxaml.net/